# Azure DevOps Artifacts/Connect to feed/Python credentials expiration

Tags: azure-devops

We host python packages on Azure DevOps and to make them accessible to users a pip.ini file is created on user's machine where we place a token generated from Artifacts / Connect to feed / Python / Generate Python credentials.

It was observed that with some time credentials stop working.

1. Does credentials expire? We didn't find anywhere in the documentation after which period of time the credentials expire.
2. Is it possible to control credentials lifetime (e.g. increase it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found answers to both my questions.

1. Credentials do expire and default expiration period is 3 months.
2. It is possible to increase (or decrease) expiration period even after credentials have been already generated. I've discovered that every time I navigate to Artifacts / Connect to feed / Python and click on "Generate Python credentials" link a new credentials are generated and they can be found by clicking on user icon (top-right) choosing "Security" and then "Personal access tokens". Here you can see all generated tokens, you can Revoke them or edit. When editing you can change Expiration - the maximum duration is 1 year.

Answer (score 0):

The python credential generate in a feed is a base64 encoded JWT(JSON Web Token ). The expiration time is defined when the JWT token is generated. I don't see there is a way to expand the token, you need to generate a new token when it is expired.

If you want to find your specific expiration time, you can copy the python credentials from the ‘pip.conf’ or ‘pip.ini’ file to this link: https://jwt.io/, which will help you find your expiration time. And your python credentials in your pip.conf is between 'https://xxx:' and '@xxxx.dev.azure.com'. All the details can be found in the screenshot. You can refer to this part from this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/411817/unable-to-revoke-credentials-for-azure-python-arti.html). Hope this will help you.

[image]

Comment: Hi Hugh Lin - MSFT. Thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure it addresses my case. While working on my task I've already found the exact answers to my question and posted them in a separate answer post.